# How to create and package web component libraries for consumption across your own web ui projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, shared-libraries, web-component

I am looking at [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) in a big to put together the simplest library of components as a proof of concept.  The question here is around development environment and distribution.

The library will be written in [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).  Lets say this is the simplest component:

**MyFirstComponent.ts**

```
class MyFirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.textContent = "Lorem ipsum";
    }
}

customElements.define('my-first-component', MyFirstComponent);
```

### Questions

How can I share *MyFirstComponent library* with other projects I have/will create?  I am looking from a private perspective without putting components into the public domain, although I am interested to see any options here.

Would I deploy both `Typescript` and `Javascript` files from my library?

I am after any professional guidance of anyone who does this for public projects or internal projects within a company.

#### Scenario

Suppose I have created *Project 1* as a `nodejs` project and I want to consume the *MyFirstComponent library*.  I don't want both *Project 1* and *MyFirstComponent library* to reside in the same `git repository`.

The mechanism would hopefully integrate into a CI/CD workflow.

#### Investigations and findings

So far my research has not resulted in many findings.

I have come across [bit.dev](https://bit.dev/) which seems to offer the above workflow with other nice bells and whistles.

Alternatively the only other way I was thinking would be to create the library as a `nodejs` project and push it to the npm repository - then install the *MyFirstComponent library* package in projects.

I am asking a different question to this [micro-frontends-web-components-and-sharing-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561807/micro-frontends-web-components-and-sharing-libraries)

Comment: [Open Web Components](https://open-wc.org/) has a lot of good recommendations.

Comment: @abraham thanks that looks good.